# Finding and changing value in table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with images in SQL database.
It looks something like this.

```
SELECT * FROM eshop_images WHERE fg_idProduct='$id' AND main='1'
+----------+-----+------+--------------+
| idImages | url | main | fg_idProduct |
+----------+-----+------+--------------+
|  1       | x   | 0    |      1       |
|  2       | x   | 1    |      1       |
|  3       | x   | 0    |      1       |
|  4       | x   | 0    |      2       |
|  5       | x   | 0    |      2       |
|  6       | x   | 0    |      2       |
|  7       | x   | 1    |      2       |
+----------+-----+------+--------------+
```

Each product can only have one main image, but what if I want to set some other image which is 0 as main one?

I have to go through the whole table where fg_idProduct=$id and SET them to null. I don't know how to do this, can somebody help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Something like `UPDATE eshop_images SET main = NULL WHERE fg_idProduct='$id' AND main='1'`?

Comment: I'm not clear... do you want to set an image to main =1 record and an another image to all the other record with main=0 of that particular product?

Comment: Each product (fg_idProduct, for example 1) can have only one main image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE eshop_images
SET main = 0
WHERE main = 1
AND fg_idProduct = $id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE eshop_images
SET main = 0
WHERE main = 1
AND fg_idProduct = $id
```